# Python Java Socket Issues

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am having an issue with Java ServerSocket and Python where I have an multithreaded echo server (Written in Java) that can communicate with multiple java clients. This all works fine.

When I try to connect with a python client, the python client can receive data from the server but when it sends data the server appears never to receive it.

I can only see the data at the server when i try to send 500K + bytes. While i can now see the data its is incomplete and out of sync.

I tested the follwing example code and it works fine with python:
http://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/how-to-connect-a-python-client-to-java-server-with-tcp-sockets/

The only real difference is that in the code from the link it uses:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),
```

Where as in my server I use:

```
streamOut = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream())); 
streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Could this be causing the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example, the PrintWriter was set to autoflush. This means that when `println()` is called, the buffer will be flushed and, consequently, sent to the network. You however, use a BufferedOutputStream and probably forgot to `flush()` your OutputStream.

Comment: Yea, it seems to be that issue but there is no way that I have found at the moment to flush the buffer in python. It seems to rely on a EOL to send. Is there an alternative way to make it flush ?

Comment: Is there a method flush()?

Comment: unfortunately not. We have re coded into java all is good now =)

Answer (score 0):

I think your python client isn't flushing the stream, which is why java server only gets data after the buffer on the client is full.